# Partial view uses wrong css stylesheet,even without link

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

First i created partial view named "showCatButton.cshtml" and associated with CategoryList2.css stylesheet.

```css
body {

}

#mainMenu{
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    list-style-type:none;
}
.subMenu {
     list-style-type:none;
}
li
{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #45484d 0%,#000000 100%);
    color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
li:hover
{
    color:black;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #e6e6e6 30%,#e6e6e6 40%,#e6e6e6 50%
    , #f2f2f2 60%, #f2f2f2 70%, #f2f2f2 80%, #f2f2f2 90%, #f2f2f2 100%);
}
#mainMenu li ul {
    display:none;
}
#mainMenu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/CategoryList2.css"/>
</head>

<body> 
      <ul id="mainMenu">
         some-unimportant code.
       </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Next i created Header partial view.With following code.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="Header">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Main
            </li>
            <li>
                Delivery methods
            </li>
            <li>
                About shop
            </li>
            <li>
                Contacts
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Even without link it uses CategoryList2.css stylesheet.In spite of i didn't add any link.
I add partial views to link,by following coode.

```html
@using OnlineShop.Models;
@using System.Data.Entity;


    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Main page</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/MainPage.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialViews/Header.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div id="CategoryList">
          @Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialViews/showCatButton.cshtml")   
    </div><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

What's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Those are not partial views, they are full blown html pages. Think of a partial view as a bit of html which gets included inside its parent view. Don't have any html body or head tags. You already inherit those from the parent.

I would keep the styles and scripts in one place, which is the parent page. Just assume you have everything available in your partial views.

Comment: I removed <html><head><body> tags,and get same problems.About views,if i don't use link tag,should partial view use any stylesheet by default?

Comment: have a look at the html once your page loads, you should see easily which stylesheets are loaded